# How to quickly check if a number is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, primality-test

Let say I've found a very very very long prime number. I know it's prime but I need to have a proof. Is there any fast way how to check if a number is really prime?

Let say I've found the longest prime number, longer than [the longest known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number) and I want to confirm it in very short time (seconds). Is it possible?

Comment: If you figure a way out let me know haha

Comment: How do you know it's a prime number if you don't have a proof?

Comment: If I knew an answer to this question, I'd probably be holding a Fields medal by now...

Comment: This has NO answer till date.

Comment: Ask the NSA or the CIA. If anybody knows, they do.

Comment: It won't take seconds. But if it really is larger than the largest known prime, a few weeks of CPU time shouldn't be too costly...

Comment: The Lucas-Lehmer test on a CPU for a number of this magnitude takes about 6 days using optimized code.  That is specific to Mersenne numbers, and for will be at least as fast as a Fermat test, which is the simplest decent compositeness (probable primality) test.  So clearly our time scales are way off from what you would like, and we still just have a PSP, not a SPSP and certainly not a proven prime.  Without some special form you're practically limited to ~40k digits (ECPP using Primo, a nice workstation/server, and a few months).  This is rather small compared to the recent Mersenne primes.

Answer (score 11):

If the number is of general form, fastest would be one of the modern versions of ECPP. This is several orders of magnitude faster than AKS.

If you can tolerate a tiny probability of error, the Miller-Rabin test works very well here.

If you can tolerate error, but only infinitesimally small, the Frobenius tests can provide much better worst-case error bounds than Miller-Rabin.

If the number is of special form the Lucas test or its variants might be applicable.

Comment: For the purpose of this question -- a large number claimed to be prime, but without any evidence -- I _highly_ recommend Miller-Rabin. A test might take a few months on a good computer if it's close to the maximum known, or longer if it's far beyond. But this is much better than the time it would take for a full proof.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the Fastest method known till date is - [AKS Primality Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)

However it won't be able to find the longest prime number within seconds.

Comment: This is an extremely slow test, even with Bernstein's modifications.